# Excel find last match from two tables

Tags: excel, excel-formula, match, lookup

I'm looking for a way to find the last instance on an entry in the columns A,B and get the corresponding values from columns C,D

In the example below value for Henry is 1374 and value for Amy is 1124

[image: Example]

Name1 corresponds to Value1 and Name2 corresponds to Value2.
Is there a formula to find the last entry from both columns Name1 and Name2 and return the corresponding Value1 or Value2

Raw data pasted below:

```
Name1   Name2   Value1  Value2
Sara    Amy     1265    1241
John    Sara    1142    1214
Amy     Henry   1295    1121
Amy     John    1175    1323
Sara    John    1085    1251
Sara    Henry   1242    1374
Amy     Sara    1124    1055
```

Answer (score 2):

**Assumptions:**

Data Grid is in cells `A1:D8`.
Values "Henry" & "Amy" are in cell `A10` & `A11` respectively.

**Formula implementation:**

In cell `B10` following formula is implemented.

*Alternative 1:*

`=INDEX($C$2:$D$8,MAX(IFERROR(LOOKUP(2,1/($A$2:$A$8=A10),ROW($A$2:$A$8)),-1),IFERROR(LOOKUP(2,1/($B$2:$B$8=A10),ROW($B$2:$B$8)),-1))-1,IF(IFERROR(LOOKUP(2,1/($A$2:$A$8=A10),ROW($A$2:$A$8)),-1)>IFERROR(LOOKUP(2,1/($B$2:$B$8=A10),ROW($B$2:$B$8)),-1),1,2))`

*Alternative 2 (slightly shorter than 1):*

`=INDEX($C$2:$D$8,LOOKUP(2,1/SEARCH(A10&",",$A$2:$A$8&","&$B$2:$B$8&",",1),ROW($A$2:$A$8))-1,IF(IFERROR(LOOKUP(2,1/($A$2:$A$8=A10),ROW($A$2:$A$8)),-1)>IFERROR(LOOKUP(2,1/($B$2:$B$8=A10),ROW($B$2:$B$8)),-1),1,2)).`

To be copied down as much needed.

Notice -1 value after `MAX()` function which is used to adjust row number. It should be always n-1 considering data starts at nth row.

Comment: Thank you @ImaginaryHuman072889. One small cut down without resorting to CSE would be: `=INDEX($C$2:$D$8,LOOKUP(2,1/SEARCH(A10&",",$A$2:$A$8&","&$B$2:$B$8&",",1),ROW($A$2:$A$8))-1,IF(IFERROR(LOOKUP(2,1/($A$2:$A$8=A10),ROW($A$2:$A$8)),-1)>IFERROR(LOOKUP(2,1/($B$2:$B$8=A10),ROW($B$2:$B$8)),-1),1,2))`. But yours is better.

Answer (score 2):

Slightly shorter:

```
= INDEX($C$1:$D$8,MAX(IF($A$1:$B$8=A10,ROW($A$1:$B$8))),MATCH(A10,
  INDEX($A$1:$B$8,MAX(IF($A$1:$B$8=A10,ROW($A$1:$B$8))),0),0))
```

Note this is an array formula, so you must press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> rather than just <kbd>Enter</kbd> after typing the formula.

See below for working example.

[image]

Comment: Very nice, neat answer :) +1

Comment: @CallumDA Thanks! I was waiting for you to say "the OP definitely didn't say they wanted to use `INDEX`"... hahaha

Answer (score 2):

I've been trying to remember another method I've seen for 2d lookup (I can't find the link any more). It's basically like this

```
=INDIRECT(TEXT(MAX((ROW($A$2:$B$8)*100+COLUMN($A$2:$B$8))*($A$2:$B$8=A10))+2,"R0C00"),FALSE)
```

entered as an array formula using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>Enter</kbd>.

So the idea is that you generate a number from the row and column where the last occurrence of the name is located (so for Henry it would be 702).

The you format it to give R7C02 and feed this in to an indirect to give the reference to the cell in RC notation. The column plus 2 gives the cell that you want.

You might notice that this would fail if column>99, but you can make the multiplier as big as you want.

[image]

Comment: `INDIRECT` seems non-ideal considering it is volatile.

Comment: I will leave the votes to speak for themselves...so far +1 for mine and +2 for the others seems pretty fair :-)

Comment: Not saying it's an invalid solution, just that I typically don't use volatile functions unless absolutely necessary. The only case I've found when `INDIRECT` is unavoidable is if the sheet name itself depends on the value in a cell.

Comment: Yes - the trade-off is arguably more flexibility but I do agree with you. The other time I've found them useful is generating a set of numbers like row(indirect(a1&":"&a2)) where the contents of a1 and a2 can vary.

Comment: Usually if I want to generate an array like that I'll use the non-volatile formula `ROW(INDEX($A:$A,1):INDEX($A:$A,A1))` where `A1` contains the array length. This form is still slightly volatile - any changes to the `A` column would cause recalculation. But you could just replace `$A:$A` with something like `$ZZ:$ZZ` or something just to a column far off to the right off of where your data actually ends. This way you practically guarantee it won't update when unnecessary. I agree it is a trade-off, but I'd rather have a longer non-volatile formula than a shorter volatile formula.

Comment: IMHO this is a tricky question.. any working answer is useful and deserves an upvote!+1